# Simple trigger generates code coverage error

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment, change-set

So I have a trigger and my production org has no Apex Classes.  I'm trying to deploy this trigger to production but I'm getting a code coverage error.  How can I deploy this trigger to production?

The only code I have in this production org is about 5 visualforce pages and 0 apex classes.

Comment: You need to create a test class for the trigger before deploying it. Add it to the change set with the apex trigger and execute it while deploying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to deploy any `Apex Trigger`, Salesforce requires that the trigger body has  *greater than* 0% code coverage, in addition to requiring that system-wide coverage be *at least* 75%. So you cannot deploy an `Apex Trigger` to production without any `Apex Class`, you need at least one to generate the necessary coverage.

Take a look at [How To Test Your Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_To_Test_Your_Apex_Triggers) and the [Testing Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers) Trailhead Module if you need to better understand how to write such a test.

Comment: Is this still true ? I think nowadays he can specify "RunSpecifiedTests" and deploy his trigger only (assuming trigger will have 75%).

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm

Comment: Absolutely still true. All triggers must have at least some coverage for a deployment to succeed.